# Заполнить переменные через foreach

Tags: c#

Есть 4 переменных и список. Нужно пробежаться по списку (он может содержать от 2 до 3 значений) и заполнить ими переменные.

```
foo1 = "";
foo2 = "";
foo3 = "";
foo4 = "";

foreach (string el in al_ready)
    {
    }
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: никак это не сделать. Во всяком случае, в рамках разумного. Если ваши 4 переменные семантически связаны друг с другом, то используйте вместо них любой подходящий контейнер,в противном случае вам придется писать так называемый китайский код

Comment: @Suliman3, 
@DreamChild тут абсолютно прав: даже исходя из названия ваших переменных видно, что они все же логически связаны. Если боитесь контейнерных типов, используйте простые массивы, которые также имеют интерфейс IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное, что приходит на ум:

```
try
{
    foo1 = al_ready[1];
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    foo1="Пусто :)";
}

try
{
    foo2=al_ready[2];
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    foo2="Пусто :)";
}
//и так далее
```

На изящность решения не претендую)))

Comment: Оно ругается:
Неявное преобразование типа "object" в "string"

что-то не пойму. Как мне тогда к индексу элемента обратиться?

Comment: >Неявное преобразование типа "object" в "string"

ну если ваш al_ready объявлен как какой-нибудь List<object> то разумеется компилятор будет ругаться

Comment: Ну да, если al_ready не типа list<String>, то следует писать al_ready[1].toString();